# c:foreach doesn't print objects

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm extremely new to JSP. Anyway, I'm trying to print every object in a list using c:foreach but it does not work and I can't figure out why. I've already checked out similar issues but nothing has solved my problem.

```
        <h2>    

        Your account information:
        <% 
            LinkedList<BankAccount> accounts = null;
            accounts = account1.getAccountList();
            request.setAttribute("accounts", account1.getAccountList());

        %>


    </h2>


<c:foreach items="${accounts}" var="acct">
<p>${acct.accountName}</p><br/>
<p>$${acct.AccountBalance}</p><br/>
    </c:foreach>

<TD valign="top"><B><%=accounts.get(0).accountName%></b><br>
<TD valign="top"><b>$<%=accounts.get(0).AccountBalance%></b></br>
    </br></br>
<TD valign="top"><b><%=accounts.get(1).accountName%></b><br>
<TD valign="top"><b>$<%=accounts.get(1).AccountBalance%></b></br>
```

The bottom code works --- accounts.get(0), etc. But I can't use this because if I add data to the database then I have to add more code every time.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are importing the library using something similar to this line? <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, no. I added your line but it says it can't be found. I also can't find any downloads for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide info about your BankAccount class, therefore i would make an assumption:

```
package testingThings.EL.linkedlist;

public class BankAccount {
    protected String accountName;
    protected double accountBalance;

    public BankAccount(String accountName, double accountBalance) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

}
```

I changed **A**ccountBalance **a**ccountBalance to stick to the conventions.

In your JSP you need the line that LeHill mentioned.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

**Don't forget the protocol: http://**

The JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="testingThings.EL.linkedlist.BankAccount"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.LinkedList"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        LinkedList<BankAccount> accounts = new LinkedList<BankAccount>();
        accounts.add(new BankAccount("acc1", 1000.00));
        accounts.add(new BankAccount("acc2", 2000.00));

        pageContext.setAttribute("accounts", accounts);
    %>
    <c:forEach items="${accounts}" var="acct">
        <p>${acct.accountName}</p>
        <br />
        <p>${acct.accountBalance}</p>
        <br />
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

The Output in Browser:

```
acc1

1000.0

acc2

2000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have getters and setters.
Your scriptlet has the attribute name as "accountName".
JSTL expects "get" or "is" as the beggining of the beans method name.
you can't call the attribute directly.  You have to use getter methods.
if you created a method called "getAccountName" it should work.

Comment: I do have getter and setter methods. I tried changing it to "acct.getAccountName" and that didn't work either.

Comment: So, the object BankAccount has methods named getAccountName and getAccountBalance?